# How to compare two columns value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison, string-comparison

I Have a dataframe which has some unique IDs in two of the columns.for e.g

```
S.no. Column1 Column2
    1  00001x  00002x
    2  00003j  00005k
    3  00002x  00001x
    4  00004d  00008e
```

Value can be anything in the string format
I want to compare the two column in such a way that either of s.no 1 or 3 data remains. as these id contains the same information. only its order is different.

Basically if for one row value in a column 1 is X and column 2 is Y  and for other row value in column 1 is Y and in Column 2 is x then only one of the row should remain.

is that possible in python?

Comment: Since you refer to the columns as containing unique IDs, you might want to consider using Pandas MultiIndex. You could then use the sorted tuples from @mozway's answer to index your data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert your columns as [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) per row.

This will give a common order to apply `duplicated`.

Finally, slice the rows using the previous output as mask:

```py
mask = df.filter(like='Column').apply(frozenset, axis=1).duplicated()
df[~mask]
```

previous answer using [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```py
mask = df.filter(like='Column').apply(lambda x: tuple(set(x)), axis=1).duplicated()
df[~mask]
```

*NB. Using a set or sorted requires to convert as tuple (`lambda x: tuple(sorted(x))`) as the `duplicated` function hashes the values, which is not possible with mutable objects*

output:

```
   S.no. Column1 Column2
0      1  00001x  00002x
1      2  00003j  00005k
3      4  00004d  00008e
```

Comment: You can use `apply(frozenset, axis=1)` to shorten it ;)